# Apply a CSS filter only on background

Tags: css

In the following snippet, I have applied a blur filter on `.sub-menu` but I the text is also filtered.

How can I apply the blur filter **only on the background and not the text**?

```css
.sub-menu {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.sub-menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #888888;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 0 12px;
}
.sub-menu li a:hover {
  color: black;
}
.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);  /* Chrome, Opera */
  -moz-filter: blur(10px);
  -ms-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
  padding: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="#">EDIT BOOK</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">NEW</a>
        <li><a href="#">BROWSE</a>
          <li><a href="#">APPROVAL</a>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why are you going for blur filters? You can achieve this by using `text-shadow` as well.

Comment: but what I want is for entire ul background

Answer (score 5):

You can apply the blur filter on a pseudo element and stack it behind the `.sub-menu` content :

```css
.sub-menu {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.sub-menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #888888;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 0 12px;
}
.sub-menu li a:hover {
  color: black;
}
.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0
}
.sub-menu:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background:url('http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-640-480-6.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  /* Chrome, Opera */
  -moz-filter: blur(10px);
  -ms-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="#">EDIT BOOK</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">NEW</a>
        <li><a href="#">BROWSE</a>
          <li><a href="#">APPROVAL</a>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry. I try this but seems nothing happened?

Comment: @LateBloomer have you applied a background on the pseudo element like in my example snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest more to add separate div wich is blured and put your sub-menu over it:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
.sub-menu {
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    z-index:1;
}



.sub-menu li a {
    display:block;
    color:#888888;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:32px;
    padding:0 12px;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover {
    color:black;
}

.sub-menu {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    padding:0
}
.blured{
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px); /* Chrome, Opera */
    -moz-filter: blur(10px);
    -ms-filter: blur(10px);   
    filter: blur(10px);
}
</style>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
            <li><a href="#">EDIT BOOK</a>
              <div style="position:relative">
                <div class="blured">
                    bla bla <br> bla bla bla
                </div>
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">NEW</a>
                <li><a href="#">BROWSE</a>
                <li><a href="#">APPROVAL</a>
              </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `backdrop-filter` property on the child element. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter)

It now has [sufficient](https://caniuse.com/css-backdrop-filter) browser support, although in 2023 you'll probably still want to also include a `-webkit-` prefix.